# Jenkins Slave Service Not Running: How to Debug

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins set-up where there is a master running on OS X with a Windows slave running on the same box as VM.

On many occasions when the VM is restarted the Jenkins service appears to either not start or possible encounters an error.

The set-up of the service looks correct and the VM is configured to automatically login as the Jenkins user, when its manually started everything seems to work fine so I can only assume the problem is on start-up of the box.

I have two questions:

- Are there any well known gotcha's that can cause this?
- Does anyone have some good strategies for debugging this? I'm assuming the answer will be somewhere in the Windows Logs but finding it is proving difficult (since the box and the user both contain the word Jenkins a simple find isn't helpful).